# Align list of buttons horizontal with auto-layout

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton, autolayout

I am creating a number of UIButton´s programmatically with auto-layout:

```
for (int i=0; i<buttonsArray.count; i++) {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",titleString]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    button.tag =i;     
    [view addSubview:button];

    // check if first button or button would exceed maxWidth
    if ((i == 0) || (runningWidth + button.frame.size.width > maxWidth)) {
        // wrap around into next line
        runningWidth = button.frame.size.width;

        if (i== 0) {
            // first button (top left)
            // horizontal position: same as previous leftmost button (on line above)
            NSLayoutConstraint *horizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                       toItem:reuseView
                                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                                                     constant:5];
            [reuseView addConstraint:horizontalConstraint];

            // vertical position:
            NSLayoutConstraint *verticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                     toItem:reuseView
                                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                                 multiplier:1.0f
                                                                                   constant:5];
            [reuseView addConstraint:verticalConstraint];


        } else {
            // put it in new line
            UIButton *previousLeftmostButton = [buttons objectAtIndex:indexOfLeftmostButtonOnCurrentLine];

            // horizontal position: same as previous leftmost button (on line above)
            NSLayoutConstraint *horizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousLeftmostButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
            [reuseView addConstraint:horizontalConstraint];

            // vertical position:
            NSLayoutConstraint *verticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousLeftmostButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:verticalSpaceBetweenButtons];
            [reuseView addConstraint:verticalConstraint];

            indexOfLeftmostButtonOnCurrentLine = i;
        }
    } else {
        // put it right from previous buttom
        runningWidth += button.frame.size.width + horizontalSpaceBetweenButtons;

        UIButton *previousButton = [buttons objectAtIndex:(i-1)];

        // horizontal position: right from previous button
        NSLayoutConstraint *horizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:horizontalSpaceBetweenButtons];
        [reuseView addConstraint:horizontalConstraint];

        // vertical position same as previous button
        NSLayoutConstraint *verticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
        [reuseView addConstraint:verticalConstraint];
    }

    [buttons addObject:button];
}
```

So I am getting a interface like this:

[image]

However, I need align the buttons horizontally in the center of the view?
Any idea how to make this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to put this into a container UIView and centre the view within its container.

Apples documentation also suggests an alternative of creating two views one before the first and one at the end and make these view's width to be equal. I find this to be a bit more effor t in most cases.